# Oxford proposal: status of stakers

Tags: staking

Can the adoption of this proposal and the implementation of staking affect users in certain countries from a legal point of view?

Answer (score 1):

It is always advisable to consult with a lawyer in the relevant jurisdiction.

This being said, Staking as proposed in Adaptive Issuance has two main effects:

- unlike a delegator, a staker puts their tez at risk: if the baker equivocates, the staker loses funds. It is similar to Cosmos staking, so legal answers applicable to Cosmos might also be relevant here.
- reward distribution to stakers is in-protocol, so the baker never has dominion and control over their staker's rewards. This is in contrast with delegation rewards where the baker has to operate third party software to redistribute rewards. It shifts responsibility of distribution away from the baker and to the protocol itself.

Note that accepting stakers is opt-in. It will be disabled by default if/when Adaptive Issuance activates.